# Syntax error with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, beautifulsoup

I've gone through so many documentation but they don't offer examples like this. I've tried to debug this for over 3 hours, but still doesn't work.

```
import urllib.request, string, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

csvfile = open('people.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')

peoplefile = open('people.txt', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(timfile.read())
tag = soup.marker

for tag in soup.find_all('marker'):
    print tag['firstname']
    data=[[tag['firstname'], tag['lastname']]]
    csvwriter.writerows(data)

csvfile.close()
peoplefile.close()
```

I get this message from command prompt:

```
(everything before is fine)...
>>> tag = soup.marker
>>> for tag in soup.find_all('marker'):
...     print tag['firstname']
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print tag['firstname']
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>     data=[[tag['firstname'], tag['lastname']]]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    data=[[tag['firstname'], tag['lastname']]]
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>     csvwriter.writerows(data)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
... csvfile.close()
>>> peoplefile.close()
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In python3 you need to treat `print` as a function:

```
print(tag['firstname'])
```

instead of

```
print tag['firstname']
```

See this [Python3 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> The print statement has been replaced with a print() function, with keyword arguments to replace most of the special syntax of the old print statement

Comment: Thank you, what does this keyerror mean? >>> print(tag['firstname'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py3.4.egg\bs4\element
.py", line 905, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'firstname'

Comment: It means that the key `firstname` doesn't exist in your dictionary `tag`

Comment: try `print(tag.keys())` to see all keys available to you.

Comment: Are you printing that from the python shell? You need to put that after the line `for tag in soup.find_all('marker'):`

Comment: OMG I got it by getting rid of an extra > between tags in the raw html file. Thanks, and love you!